# Python with sql server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

After fetching records from sql query using pyodbc, how do i access particular record and store it in a variable.

P.S.  I am novice to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=SQLS;UID=test01;PWD=test01')
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create table rvtest (col1 int, col2 float, col3 varchar(10))")
cursor.execute("insert into rvtest values(1, 10.0, \"ABC\")")
cursor.execute("select * from rvtest")

   records =cursor.fetchall()
    for row in records:
        print("Id: ", row[0])
        print("Name: ", row[1])`
```

If you want to fetch 2nd row 5th column use:

```
records[1][4]
```

Comment: In my code I have used cursor.fetchall. I mean for ith row and jth column value, need to be accessed in records. How do I do in python? E.g records have 10 rows 5 columns, i want to get 2nd row 5 th column value in a variable.

Comment: Updated the solution as per the requirement.

Comment: @vikas If this solution solved your query, don't forget to upvote the answer.